# DataForm, DropBox and data annotations (description and such)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I've got a DataForm in which I replace some TextBox fields with DropBoxes to imitate a lookup using the AutoGeneratingField event.

However, when I do that, I loose any data annotations that could otherwise be used (such as a description which I specified in my data model).

Is there a way to get these values from the data model without resorting to auto-generated fields? The `DataFormAutoGeneratingFieldEventArgs` parameter doesn't seem to contain them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the DataField.PropertyPath property to the name of the model property with metadata.